# Why won't this data bind? An odd case in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is the controller:

```
.controller('DataCtrl', function($ionicPlatform, $scope, $rootScope) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
        $scope.analyticsOn = localStorage.analytics; 
        console.log('analytics are', $scope.analyticsOn);

        $scope.counter = 0;
        $scope.change = function(){
            $scope.counter++;
            console.log('analytics are ' + $scope.analyticsOn);
            localStorage.analytics = $scope.analyticsOn; 
        }
    })
});
```

And here is the html:

```
<li class="item item-toggle">
   <i class="icon ion-cloud"></i> Data Tracking is {{analyticsOn}} {{counter}}
      <label class="toggle toggle-balanced">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="analyticsOn" ng-change="change()">
          <div class="track">
             <div class="handle"></div>
          </div>
       </label>
    </li>
```

Pressing the toggle gets the console message "analytics are undefined" no matter what.

Yet, and here is the thing, in the app the {{analyticsOn}} updates and flips from true to false and the {{counter}} counts up from an initial value of zero.

So I know that -

- a. Two way data binding IS working, or the counter wouldn't work.
- b. analyticsOn IS changing.

So why don't the console.logs show it? The plan is to put the value back into the localStorage.analytics for data persistence but this is the first time I've used ng-change. If I did this in pure JavaScript it would be fine.

Anyone?

EDIT: I ended up abandoning this as I heard about ngStorage - a plugin that lets you bind directly into and out of localStorage without the intermediate step of getting data from the model into localStorage.

That itself has brought up it's own issues, which I'll be asking questions about elsewhere.

Comment: I had a similar issue on an app I was making recently and was able to solve it by creating a model object within the scope and using dot notation to access all my model properties within the binding. I'm pretty new to angular though, so I can't adequately explain why this works, but I would give it a try.

Comment: Could you try `ng-change="change(analyticsOn)"` and then use the parameter of `scope.change = function(analyticsOn)  {...}`?

Comment: always have a `dot` in `ng-model` otherwise you are trying to 2 way bind to a primitive which can cause lots of problems in child scopes

Comment: Yes, I can use change({{analyticsOn}}) but this missed the entire point of two way data-binding. It on passed the correct value for analyticsOn but the console log is STILL wrong and comes out as "undefined".

Comment: I would go with @charlietfl and put `analyticsOn` in an simple object literal: http://plnkr.co/edit/UfYwB6DWlPJpycVD4zmm?p=preview (Basically instead of `$scope.analyticsOn` use something like `$scope.foobar.analyticsOn`). I have had similar problems but cannot recall exactly what was the reason. I can also not explain why not defining the variable directly in the $scope solves the problem :-(

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect create demo that replicates problem...likely related to child scopes which is why `dot` is so important

Comment: If I try $scope.foobar.analyticsOn I get an error saying "can't read property  analyticsOn of undefined variable 'foobar'"

Answer (score 0):

It could possible to update both `localStorage` & `$scope` variable together by storing whole localStorage in one scope variable, By making this change you could get rid of `ng-change` directive too.

**Markup**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="localStorage.analyticsOn" ng-change="change()">
```

**Code**

```
.controller('DataCtrl', function($ionicPlatform, $scope, $rootScope) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
        $scope.localStorage= localStorage; 
        console.log('analytics are', $scope.localStorage.analyticsOn);

        $scope.counter = 0;
        $scope.change = function(){
            $scope.counter++;
            console.log('analytics are ' + $scope.localStorage.analyticsOn);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect for that we need to bind event on change of that element.

Comment: I still don't get your code. In the first console.log where is $scope.analyticsOn defined?

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect that my bad in copy paste..take a look at my updated answer

Comment: i still don't get how this is storing anything in local storage.

Answer (score -3):

The first console.log line is wrong it is

`console.log('analytics are', $scope.analyticsOn);`

should it be `console.log('analytics are' + $scope.analyticsOn);`

Comment: You can add as many comma separated parameters to console as you want

Comment: No, the comma is a legit way of doing it. I've tried both anyway.

Comment: Yes, but when I tested his code it worked with a + and not a comma.

Comment: I don't know, maybe your Google Ultron is not supporting this, but for all others https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Console/log